# Angular: Is it possible for typescript imports auto locate files?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular. Angular uses typescript. In Angular when you want to import a file you do something like:

```
import { MyService } from '../../../folder/child-folder/my-service.service';
```

As I continue coding my project I am moving folders from one place to another time and again. This comes with the need to update the new relative location of all the imported files. This process can be tedious depending on the number of files you have moved.

What can I do so that my files are always auto located regardless of the location of the importing file? For example like Angular does it with their in-built files like:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: There is also an AI plug in from Microsoft, it's pretty good.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please provide a link for further research?

Comment: Go to visual studio code marketplace look for 'imports'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `tsconfig.json` to declare paths

```
"lib": [
    ...
],


"paths": {
  "@myfolder/*": [
    "src/path/to/folder/*"
  ]
}
```

And then use it like this

```
import { MyService } from '@myfolder/child-folder/my-service.service';
```